# Timing Attack on OpenSSL by Brumley

Tags: tls, openssl, attack, timing-attack

I am referring to this paper by David Brumley and Dan Boneh: [*Remote Timing Attacks are Practical*](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/ssl-timing.pdf) (In proceedings of the 12th Usenix Security Symposium, 2003).

In this paper on [page 4](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/ssl-timing.pdf#page=4), Brumley specifies the following steps :

> Step 1. Calculate guess, $g$.
>
> Step 2. Calculate $U_g = g\cdot R^{-1}\bmod N$
>
> Step 3. Send $U_g$ to Server for decryption and note the time before and after.

My queries:

1. How should $g$ look like for a 3 bit combination of "101" when we are searching for peaks ?
2. The CLIENT_KEY_EXCHANGE message, which will be $g$ here, should be unencrypted. Am I right ?